# How to use write statement in fortran to call another self defined function?

Tags: c++, io, fortran, gfortran

I have a C++ file I/O function. I want to call the function in fortran's write-statement. The write can use some indexed device like `write(3, *)`. I know how to do it by just define a new function. But can write statement call my function?

Comment: Do you want IO from the C++ function to go to the same place as the IO that results from the Fortran write or print statement?

Comment: @IanH want to write some i/o with our own api.

Answer (score 3):

Do not mix Fortran and C++ I/O, that is a recipe for disaster.

Even calling a Fortran function that does I/O from a Fortran print statement (recursive I/O) is not permitted in many compilers and will likely stop your program. With a C++ function the odds of bad things happening are even higher.

The correct thing to do is to perform I/O only in one of the languages. For example you can write to a string in C++, return the string to Fortran and print it in Fortran. Or the opposite.